# Removing variable length whitespaces in R

Tags: regex, string, rstudio

I have a column of products where there are variable length white spaces between the strings in the product description.

Here is an example of one of the products:

```
"This  is     a product     from the product column"
"Here is        another       example from the product column"
```

I would like the string to look like this where there is just a single white space between strings:

"This is a product from the product column"

Can this be achieve for

Comment: With using PERL, you can use a lookbehind to ensure a space precedes another space, but to not match the first one [`(?<=\\s)\\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/B1FEE6/2) and remove the matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace any repeating spaces `\\s` (more than one in a row), match anytime there are two or more spaces `\\s{2,}` and replace those with only a single space. The `{2,}` means match repeats greater than two. We could set a maximum number of repeats like this `{2,7}`.

```
gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", "string   with many    spaces")
```

To do this for column names, just replace the string to be replaced with the `colnames(df)`.